# Cleaning up IF statements Python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, code-cleanup

Im trying to clean up my if statements, we're doing a group project and my counterparts says this code looks too confusing. Please give me tips on making it shorter or cleaning it up, the code currently looks like this;

```
for r in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
 
            # Skip, if it contains a mine
            if numbers[r][col] == -1:
                continue
 
            # Check up  
            if r > 0 and numbers[r-1][col] == -1:
                numbers[r][col] = numbers[r][col] + 1
            # Check down    
            if r < n-1  and numbers[r+1][col] == -1:
                numbers[r][col] = numbers[r][col] + 1
            # Check left
            if col > 0 and numbers[r][col-1] == -1:
                numbers[r] = numbers[r] + 1
            # Check right
            if col < n-1 and numbers[r][col+1] == -1:
                numbers[r][col] = numbers[r][col] + 1
            # Check top-left    
            if r > 0 and col > 0 and numbers[r-1][col-1] == -1:
                numbers[r][col] = numbers[r][col] + 1
            # Check top-right
            if r > 0 and col < n-1 and numbers[r-1][col+1]== -1:
                numbers[r][col] = numbers[r][col] + 1
            # Check below-left  
            if r < n-1 and col > 0 and numbers[r+1][col-1]== -1:
                numbers[r][col] = numbers[r][col] + 1
            # Check below-right
            if r < n-1 and col< n-1 and numbers[r+1][col+1]==-1:
                numbers[r][col] = numbers[r][col] + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints of the problem, yours is a reasonable solution.  But, if you want appease your counterparts you could try something like this.  Its only real advantage is that it separates the concern of identifying valid adjacent cells from the concern of incrementing a cell's counter.  By separating the concerns you could, in theory, reuse the adjacent cell generator for other purposes, and more easily debug one or the other concern.

```
def iter_adjacent_cells(r, c, n):
    for rd in range(-1,2):
        for cd in range(-1,2):
            # skip the current cell
            if rd == 0 and cd == 0:
                continue
            if 0 <= r + rd < n and 0 <= c + cd < n:
                yield r + rd, c + cd

for r in range(n):
    for c in range(n):
 
        # Skip, if it contains a mine
        if numbers[r][c] == -1:
            continue

        for ar, ac in iter_adjacent_cells(r, c, n):
            if numbers[ar][ac] == -1:
                numbers[r][c] += 1
```